# Phabricator: Error updating working copy: Command killed by timeout after running for more

Tags: git, phabricator

I created a new observe repository and added a URL for bitbucket，when I activated this repository.

I can see this error:

> Error updating working copy: Command killed by timeout after running
>   for more than 900 seconds.

COMMAND

```
git clone --bare -- '********' '/var/repo/12'
```

STDOUT

```
Cloning into bare repository '/var/repo/12'...
```

STDERR

```
Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,18.205.93.0' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
fatal: early EOF
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHbaa.jpg)

Comment: small repository is fine, but a large repository can cause this problem, my bitbucket repository is 2G in size.

Answer (score 1):

In the repository options under **Limits** you can increase the **Clone/Fetch Timeout** from the default 900 Seconds to something bigger.